# Find items in one list but not in another in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I keep running into dead ends here, and it's killing me.

**Dataframe:**

```
accountid    col2                 col3
1            ['abc','def','xyz']  ['abc','mda','xyz','sdi']
2            ['abc','asd','xyz','dib]  ['nio','ouy','abc']
3            ['abc','def','xyz']  ['abc','mda','xyz']
```

**Notes**

*each field in col2 and col3 are lists

*fields in col2 and col3 may not have an equal number of items in the list

**Result should look like**
I'm trying to create a col4 that shows the items in col3 that are not in and col2:

```
accountid    col2                      col3                        col4
1            ['abc','def','xyz']       ['abc','mda','xyz','sdi']   ['mda','sdi']
2            ['abc','asd','xyz','dib]  ['nio','ouy','abc']         ['nio','ouy']
3            ['abc','def','xyz']       ['abc','mda','xyz']         ['mda']
```

What can I try next?

Comment: Do they need to be lists? Do you care about maintaining the order of the elements in the lists? Sets are more natural objects for this operation, can you use DataFrames of sets instead?

Comment: i've tried creating a column for set(col2) - set(col3) but that doesn't work; i get a length of values does not match the length of index. they're the same length in row count - maybe that means in number of items in a list. But they have to stay in a list format. there are unique accountids in each row; wouldn't want a row for each item in a list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Let me put it this way: would a result of col4 being {'mda', 'sdi'}, ... etc. instead of ['mda', 'sdi'] ... etc. be acceptable? Note that the set version has no concept of order for 'mda' and 'sdi'.

Comment: Oh sorry - yes ['mda','sdi'] would be totally fine. doesn't really matter the format - as long as it shows the different items in col3 (from col2)

Answer (score 3):

Let us do

```
s=df.col3.apply(set)-df.col2.apply(set)
0    {sdi, mda}
1    {nio, ouy}
2         {mda}
dtype: object
df['New']=s.map(list)
```

Check the result

```
s.map(list)
0    [sdi, mda]
1    [nio, ouy]
2         [mda]
dtype: object
```

You list is not list , it is string

```
import ast
df.iloc[:,1:]=df.iloc[:,1:].applymap(ast.literal_eval)
```

Comment: This returns a list for each row but the list contains just single letters; not the full 'abc' item within the list; just ['b']

Comment: @max try using my last ast code before run above solution

Comment: I'm getting malformed node or string?

Comment: @max print df.col2[0]

Comment: you were right - the type was still a string. i converted each field in the column to a list with: df.col = df['col'].lambda c: list(literal_eval(c))). however, when running your method, there's a comma between every letter of the 'New' column.

Comment: i tried the following code: df['New'] = df.apply(lambda row: [s for s in row['col3'] if s not in row ['col2']], axis=1) but this still put a comma in between every character. any ideas?

Comment: @max you apply list to the string which will unpack each character to single object into a list

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Apply the lambda function along the column `axis=1`

```
df['col4'] = df.apply(lambda x : list(set(x['col3']).difference(set(x['col2']))), axis=1)
```

Comment: This returned column with empty lists for each field []